# How to scroll recylerview while dragging item from one adapter to another in android java

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, scroll, drag-and-drop

I am using a recylerview that contain another recylerview to show list horizontally,

- Main Recylerview scrolling vertically
- Internal Recylerview scrolling horizontally.
  The issue is that when i drag imageView from internal recylerview to another recyclerview while dragging if user reach at top or bottom of the screen main Recyclerview is not scroll to put the item in another list.. dragging is working fine and item putting from one to another is also fine.. just need to implement scrolling while dragging..

Comment: Did you try with nested scroll view for your second recyclerview?

Comment: no, should i need to put internal recyclerview in nested scrollview? but my internal recylerview is horizontall/

Comment: Yes, Try with nested scroll view

Comment: no success.....